# Does Current Time Match a Range of times?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to create a catch on an iOS app to keep people from accessing things outside of a small window.

Basically, I need the action to only fire if it is between 12-1:30PM on Sundays in London (BST Time Zone).  How would I check the current time, convert it to that time zone, and then see if it matches up?

I have tried the following, but it always shows it is between that range:

```
- (NSDate *)dateByNeutralizingDateComponentsOfDate:(NSDate *)originalDate {
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc]
                              initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];

    // Get the components for this date
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:  (NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate: originalDate];

    // Set the year, month and day to some values (the values are arbitrary)
    [components setYear:2000];
    [components setMonth:1];
    [components setDay:1];

    return [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
}

- (BOOL)isTimeOfDate:(NSDate *)targetDate betweenStartDate:(NSDate *)startDate andEndDate:(NSDate *)endDate {
    if (!targetDate || !startDate || !endDate) {
        return NO;
    }

    // Make sure all the dates have the same date component.
    NSDate *newStartDate = [self dateByNeutralizingDateComponentsOfDate:startDate];
    NSDate *newEndDate = [self dateByNeutralizingDateComponentsOfDate:endDate];
    NSDate *newTargetDate = [self dateByNeutralizingDateComponentsOfDate:targetDate];

    // Compare the target with the start and end dates
    NSComparisonResult compareTargetToStart = [newTargetDate compare:newStartDate];
    NSComparisonResult compareTargetToEnd = [newTargetDate compare:newEndDate];

    return (compareTargetToStart == NSOrderedDescending && compareTargetToEnd == NSOrderedAscending);
}
-(void)checkDate {
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE HH:mm"];
        NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"BST"];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
        NSDate *openingDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Sunday 12:00"];
        NSDate *closingDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Sunday 1:30"];
        NSDate *targetDate = [NSDate date];

        if ([self isTimeOfDate:targetDate betweenStartDate:openingDate andEndDate:closingDate]) {
            NSLog(@"TARGET IS INSIDE!");
        }else {
            NSLog(@"TARGET IS NOT INSIDE!");
        }

}
```

Comment: You are deleting the sunday ... So maybe it showed inside because of the current time within the range...

Comment: You should be doing this check on a server that you control, not a smartphone that is controlled by your users. People can (and regularly do!) change their iPhone time to be deliberately incorrect. Also some people just have it wrong (eg, maybe their time is set to 10 AM GMT but the current time is 10AM BST. A typical user wouldn't notice, but your app will break). After dealing with these issues, I've learned to _always_ use a server to determine the current time, don't do it on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to use the current time as observed in England, rather than BST specifically, as BST is British **Summer** Time. My understanding is that, during the winter, they use UTC (formerly known as GMT). Thus we should specify the time zone in a way that will select the proper offset from UTC based on the time of year.

```
static BOOL dateIsAcceptable(NSDate *date) {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/London"];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar
        components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute
        fromDate:date];
    if (components.weekday != 1) {
        return NO;
    }
    double hour = components.hour + components.minute / 60.0;
    return hour >= 12 && hour < 13.5;
}
```

Comment: Where would I want to put this bit of code?  I put it in the button to run the check and got error `Function definition is not allowed here`

Comment: It's a function you can put at the top of your file. Then call it from the place where you want to check whether a date is acceptable.